# Powershell: Convert text files to csv files

Tags: python, powershell, csv

```
$SearchFolder = "C:\Test\New folder\*.txt" 


$CSVFilePath = "C:\Test\txtfiles" # this doesn't work... 


$File = Select-String -Path $SearchFolder -Pattern new-print-server, default, dymo, zebra -NotMatch | select line, filename



$File | foreach-object {
$_.line = $_.line.replace("^",",")

}


$File | export-csv -path $CSVFilePath -NoTypeInformation


$csv = Get-Content -path $CSVFilePath



$csv | Out-File $CSVFilePath -Encoding utf8


Invoke-Item $CSVFilePath
```

This is a script I got from online and I would like to convert a folder of text files to csv files.
This code only allows me to put all the txt files into one csv files.
I would like to convert multiple txt files to multiple csv files with the same names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Select-String you need to quote the Pattern e.g.:

```
Select-String -Path $SearchFolder -Pattern 'new-print-server, default, dymo, zebra' -NotMatch | select line, filename
```

See if this gets you closer:

```
$files = Get-ChildItem "C:\Test\New folder\*.txt"
foreach ($file in $files) {
    $notMatchedLines = $file | Select-String -Pattern 'new-print-server, default, dymo, zebra' -NotMatch | select line,filename
    $notMatchedLines | foreach {$_.line = $_.line.replace("^",",")}
    $notMatchedLines | Export-Csv ([io.path]::ChangeExtension($file.Fullname, '.csv')) -NoTypeInformation -Encoding UTF8
}
```

Comment: Thanks for you help. But it gives me 2 columns Line and filename and all the data come together in one column(line). I don't want to see the Line or Filenames.. I would like to convert txt to csv file with no change.. I know the Script that I post have Select Line,Filename... sorry about confusion

Comment: In that case, change the last line to `$file | Export-Csv ...`.