# Convert text file data to csv powershell

Tags: powershell

Below is one of the file data I have in text file

```
B97SW | CHANGED | rc=0 >>
Server Name";"SystemFolderPath";"IdenityReference";"FileSystemRights";"Vulnerable
B97SW;C:\Windows\system32;CREATOR OWNER;268435456;No
B97SW;C:\Windows\system32;NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM;268435456;No
B97SW;C:\Windows\system32;NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM;Modify, Synchronize;No
........
```

I am trying to replace **";"** with **","** and write to csv.

Below is the code I wrote but it is not writing the data in csv.

```
$FileList = Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\Files"

$props=[ordered]@{
     ServerName=''
     SystemFolderPath=''
     IdenityReference=''
     FileSystemRights=''
     Vulnerable=''
}
New-Object PsObject -Property $props | 
     Export-Csv C:\2021.csv -NoTypeInformation

$FinalData = @()

foreach($n_file in $FileList)
{
    $FileName = $n_file.FullName
    $FileContent = Get-Content -Path $FileName | Select-Object -Skip 2


    foreach($line in $FileContent)
    {
        $line = $line -replace(";",",")
        $line | Export-Csv -Path C:\2021.csv -Append -NoTypeInformation -Force
    }    
}
```

output I am getting

```
"ServerName","SystemFolderPath","IdenityReference","FileSystemRights","Vulnerable"
"","","","",""
,,,,
,,,,
```

Please let me know what is wrong  I am doing here.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Powershell: Convert text files to csv files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19052357/powershell-convert-text-files-to-csv-files)

Comment: @zerocukor287: I am following the same process of replace and write but still i am getting blank csv

Comment: Your input file does not look like a varlid almost-CSV file (or TSV, or SSV if that were a thing). In particular, the missing opening quote before `Server Name` will throw off any attempt to parse this without further modifications. Also, is `B97SW | CHANGED | rc=0 >>` part of the data, or just spurious junk?

Comment: @tripleee If you look at the `Get-Content` line, the code is skipping the first two lines, propably because of that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> $line | Export-Csv -Path C:\2021.csv -Append -NoTypeInformation -Force
> ```

This doesn't work because `Export-Csv` expects object(s) with properties, but `$line` is just a string. You need to parse it into an object first, using `ConvertFrom-Csv`.

Try this:

```
$FileList = Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\Files"

foreach($n_file in $FileList)
{
    $FileName = $n_file.FullName

    Get-Content -Path $FileName | 
        Select-Object -Skip 2 |
        ConvertFrom-Csv -Delimiter ';' -Header ServerName, SystemFolderPath, IdenityReference, FileSystemRights, Vulnerable |
        Export-Csv -Path C:\2021.csv -Append -NoTypeInformation -Force
}
```

As we have skipped the original headers, we have to supply these through the `-Header` parameter of `ConvertFrom-Csv`.

Answer (score 0):

Your CSV file is goofed up in two ways.  First, there is a line of garbage before the header line.  Second, in the header line the semi-colons are surrounded by double quotes.  The correct form would be to surround the header names with quotes instead.

Once these format errors are fixed,  you can read the csv file with this:

```
Import-Csv myfile.csv -delimiter ";"
```

Or if you want to produce a comma delimited csv file, try this:

```
Import-Csv myfile.csv -delimiter ";" | Export-Csv newfile.csv
```

The result will be correct but it will have a lot of unnecessary double quotes.